Is it possible to create multiple accounts with identical UID (Unique ID)?
A pretty standard Unix trick is to have different user names that map to the same UID. This is used to login with different shells, possibly different home directories, different primary gid etc. In my case, I would like to be able to keep the process trees separate, but with identical home directories and permissions. The idea being that it would be a way to visually group different projects/contexts but still share files etc. Typically I have 2-4 spaces per context (work projects) and giving rise to a very long row of spaces making it difficult to navigate.
Whatever the motivation, it seems that Sonoma goes a long way to stop you from having to accounts with the same UID. I have tried changing UID with the preference pane (it silently ignores the change), with sysadminctl (it complains there is already a user with that UID) and with dscl (it complains the record already exists, although it doesn't). Is there a way? (It seems that it was possible under earlier versions of OSX, but I am unable to repeat that)
